# Difference between data redundancy and data inconsistency

Tags: database

Data is redundant if data is copied at many places, and data is inconsistent if multiple copies of the same data doesn't match. So does data inconsistency implies data redundancy?
 How can we more clearly differentiate between data inconsistency and redundancy?

Answer (score 2):

Inconsistency is not only about "*copies of data*".

Inconsistency is typically about constraints that are expected, but not enforced. For example an order without a customer (or without a product). Or a negative salary. Or a time booking where the start time is after the end time. Or a booking for a room where the dates overlap. Or two products with the same product number.

What exactly defines an "inconsistency" is a defined by the business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I think these both terms are not the same problem. Redundancy is no problem if done correctly. Even more it often is needed to do things correctly. 
Inconsistency is the result if you do redundancy incorrectly.

Inconsistency can also occur in non-redundant data, see transactions.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate inconsistencies, you should restrict the input to selector fields on a form.

The best way, of course, is to have the input field be a combo box with the data source being a table or query you supply, and limit selections to only those entries you supply in the source table/query.

The second best way would be to have that input field be an auto-open-on-type-in combo box with a data source for it being a query that gives an alphabetized list of unique values from the destination table, but should also allow "add new" values.

In either case, when the user begins typing input into that field, the combo box will open and show the matches to the first character(s) the user types. If there is a close match, the user will be able to select it, and then it will exactly match the entry listed in the combo box.

In the second case, it will also allow the user to create a new entry if what they need is not in the list.

In my experience, this is the best way to eliminate inconsistencies, and ensure any redundant data is consistent.

On the other hand, if you want to eliminate redundancy, or repeated data, such as storing all 11 characters of "Los Angeles" in every record, you should NORMALIZE your data tables, where you create a separate table containing the redundant data, and store an index to that related table in your main data record. For example, you could have a CITIES table with "Los Angeles" as entry ID 1 and "San Francisco" as entry ID 2. Then when you had 15,000 people sign up from Los Angeles and 11,000 from San Francisco, you would not have to store the names of those cities 15,000 and 11,000 times, but merely the IDs of those cities. This is called a relational database and helps to eliminate redundancy.

There is a good article on database normalization here: 
https://www.lifewire.com/database-normalization-basics-1019735